# Application language change

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I know that many questions were posted about this theme, but I cannot find question matching my case scenario, so please  help.
I need to make my aplication language correspond to the system language of a device, but I can't get it to work. I understand that if I remove `resConfig`, it will work ok, but I cannot understand why it does not work with `resConfigs "en", "in"`. By the way, I need my application to have English and Indonesian `string.xml` files. Also, I tried to update configuration by using following code:

```
val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(Locale("id"))

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        applicationContext.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    } else {
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics);
    }
```

but still it does not work. Can someone suggest something regarding this problem?
By the way I use Lingver dependecy in my project.

Comment: When you only add a string translation file, it will change the language of the app depending on the system language without the need to any coding for this.

Comment: So, why my app language doesnot changed after changing system language, but if I remove `resConfigs` from gradle file it works

Comment: yes, when you set a customized locale it will always be it if it is in Gradle or in code.

Comment: What is your solution to my problem?

Comment: Follow this link - https://devdeeds.com/android-change-language-at-runtime/

Comment: It doesn't worked for me. I think the problem is in resConfigs.